Is warning yielded by -Wc++-compat about identifiers not yet expanded by macro a false positive?
I've been compiling my C code against some very "non-default" warnings and found a potential GCC bug - a false positive caused by -Wc++-compat.  Before explaining anything, it would probably be easier to introduce the code first:
main.c
#include <stdio.h>

#define X_KEYWORDS  \
        X(bool)     \
        X(not)      \
        X(and)      \
        X(or)       \
        X(xor)      \
        X(nullptr)  \
        X(true)     \
        X(false)

int main(void)
{
#       define X(keyword) puts(#keyword);
        X_KEYWORDS
#       undef X
        return 0;
}

And when compiled with -Wc++-compat, GCC prints following diagnostic:
$ gcc main.c -Wc++-compat
main.c:5:11: warning: identifier "not" is a special operator name in C++ [-Wc++-compat]
    5 |         X(not)      \
      |           ^
main.c:6:11: warning: identifier "and" is a special operator name in C++ [-Wc++-compat]
    6 |         X(and)      \
      |           ^
main.c:7:11: warning: identifier "or" is a special operator name in C++ [-Wc++-compat]
    7 |         X(or)       \
      |           ^
main.c:8:11: warning: identifier "xor" is a special operator name in C++ [-Wc++-compat]
    8 |         X(xor)      \
      |

As you can see, it warns me about constructs inside of a macro definition; these weren't expanded anywhere yet. The body of main is irrelevant here; it can be even empty - int main(void) {} - and the same warnings would appear anyway. I just wanted to show that this specific X-Macro has a valid use case.
Those warnings never appear in the actual expanded code. My snippet expands them into string literals which appear valid to me. I do not see how it would violate C++ dialect.
Those "faulty" identifiers are the same as the ones defined in libc <iso646.h> (?).
Note that I also used other C++-specific keywords inside of the macro body, such as bool or nullptr, and the warning does not point at them.
Anyway, the mentioned behavior does not seem to occur with clang:
$ clang main.c -Wc++-compat

and compiles just fine as C++ with all compilers I have available at the moment:
$ mv main.c main.cpp
$ g++ main.cpp
$ cl main.cpp /nologo
main.cpp
$ clang++ main.cpp



Am I just safe to assume this is a GCC-specific bug?
Or is there any case those diagnostics would be valid?
Why would it only warn about stuff from <iso646.h> ?


(references)
$ uname -a
Linux MAL200424 6.11.6-arch1-1 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri, 01 Nov 2024 03:30:41 +0000 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 14.2.1 20240910

$ clang --version
clang version 18.1.8

godbolt link: https://godbolt.org/z/8jo363EbP 
GCC manual: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-14.2.0/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wc_002b_002b-compat 
about <iso646.h>: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_alternative

EDIT: Got this reported here:
https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=117902

Looks like a false-positive to me.  The warning probably trips at a phase where the identifiers are visible, before they get string-ified.

@Eljay Does this apply to C in the same way? The doc you linked explicitly refers to C++ standards.

Ah, got it! Phase 1: 3) Trigraph sequences are replaced by corresponding single-character representations. (until C++17) and similar behavior appears in C, but untill C23 and it's Phase 1: 2) instead (see translation_phases) - Trigraph sequences points to the page about operators from <iso646.h>. This probably explains why only those operators are affected.

There are no keywords in macros — there are only tokens (see C11 footnote 166: Because the controlling constant expression is evaluated during translation phase 4, all identifiers either are or are not macro names — there simply are no keywords, enumeration constants, etc.)

You need to differentiate here: bool, nullptr, false and true are keywords, but just like in C, in C++ keywords are just identifiers in the preprocessor. A warning for these at the preprocessor stage doesn't really make much sense. For not, and, or and xor it is different: These are alterantive token spellings and not identifiers, not even for the preprocessor, in C++. As a consequence they e.g. can't be used as macro names and will behave as operators in controlling arithmetic expressions of #if. So warning about these words in the preprocessor makes some sense.

@user17732522 RE: "So warning about these words in the preprocessor makes some sense" - so it's either an issue with clang or gcc, since behavior differs as clang issues no warnings at all

@sleeptightAnsiC Warnings are not standardized. Every compiler can make its own choice when and what to warn about. Clang as a rule-of-thumb attempts to implement GCC's behavior, but also sometimes intentionally deviates. And in your specific case here there isn't any immediate problem with using these words, because you use them only as token (and because the stringify operator is specified to preserve the original spelling of the token). I am just saying that in general using these words in the preprocessor may cause incompatibility between C and C++.

@Eljay # stringification is applied during macro expansion in C during translation phase 5 (see C23 5.1.1.2). Preprocessing tokens are converted to tokens in phase 7 and from there it starts to make sense to speak of identifiers. So your explanation doesn't make sense to me - this can't be explained through translation phases.

@sleeptightAnsiC Translation phases are roughly the same in C and C++. And this has nothing to do with that, see my comment above this one.

@sleeptightAnsiC Trigraphs have absolutely nothing to do with iso646.h. And trigraphs were removed in C23. I would advise to stop reading indirect sources like cppreference at this point, read the actual standard.

I think user17732522 nailed the root of the problem with these tokens.  I am now uncertain if it is a false-positive warning.



Am I just safe to assume this is a GCC-specific bug?


As you observe yourself, the diagnostics flag the definition of macro X_KEYWORDS, not the location where it is expanded.  At this point, the compiler does not know how that macro may be used, so it is probably best to characterize the behavior as GCC being exceedingly cautious, not buggy.  I take it to be telling you that there might be ways you could use that macro that would be incompatible with C++.  I anticipate that you would get additional diagnostics if you actually did use it in such a way (which you haven't).
So no, you should not take the diagnostics to be buggy, but neither should you take them as indicating that your overall program fails to be well-formed C++.


Or is there any case those diagnostics would be valid?


See above.


Why would it only warn about stuff from <iso646.h> ?


Of the particular preprocessing tokens under consideration, the ones GCC warns about are of type preprocessing-op-or-punc in C++, but of type identifier in C.  The others are of type identifier in both languages.  That appears to be what GCC means by calling those in the former group "special operator names".  That's also the basis for potential incompatibilities.

Bolinger I don't say your explanation is wrong, but I'm really not convinced by "there might be ways you could use that macro that would be incompatible" - because one could say the same about pretty much ANY macro (or template), and it doesn't mean the compiler should issue a warning by making some assumptions. To be honest, I never seen a diagnostic issued only about some token within macro definition. This is super strange. I think I will just report it to get some response, even if it's not really a bug. Thanks though, I find the second part of the answer very useful.

@sleeptightAnsiC, one cannot reasonably say the same about just any macro.  As this answer already observes, your particular macro uses tokens that are categorized differently by C and C++, and whose allowed uses are therefore fundamentally different.  Indeed, that's what the warnings are actually about.  That doesn't make the macro inherently wrong, but it does make it inherently risky.  If a use of it did end up being incompatible with C++, then I know I'd appreciate having such a warning to help me locate the source of the problem, rather than having to trace back through a macro stack.

"as GCC being exceedingly cautious, not buggy" I disagree since it doesn't warn about things that are actual C keywords (C23) and before then available as standard library identifiers. Every single identifier in the OP's X macro list is either a C keyword or a standard library identifier, regardless of C++. Buggy is the correct word here.

bool, nullptr, true and false are keywords in both languages, not valid as identifiers.

@Lundin, the preprocessor does not distinguish between keywords and identifiers.  The C++ preprocessor does distinguish between alternative operator spellings and identifiers. As this answer already explains, as preprocessing tokens, bool, nullptr, etc. are all identifiers to the C preprocessor, and they are all operator-or-punctuators to the C++ preprocessor.


Am I just safe to assume this is a GCC-specific bug?

Yes that seems likely since most optional diagnostics in gcc are quite broken since forever (I can reproduce the compiler bug down to gcc 5 and older yet).
As you say, it is senseless to warn against those reserved identifiers before they are actually used as identifiers in a C name space.
As it happens those identifiers are also reserved in C in some situations. C didn't include them as keywords like C++, but through iso646.h, which is a mandatory header for the compiler to implement.
According to C23 7.1.3 we may not declare identifiers at file scope which may collide with names of items in the standard library headers. But that is not the case here: you have not declared these as macros, but are rather using them as input arguments to macros which is fine.
A bunch of the things in the macro list is even C standard keywords now, as per C23. So it's buggy beyond just considering C++ compatibility... what about writing C code with C compatibility?


Or is there any case those diagnostics would be valid?

Only when those items from the X macro list are present as actual identifiers. Then it's not just a C++ compatibility issue but likely a C syntax error as well.


Why would it only warn about stuff from <iso646.h> ?

That does indeed not make any sense. The warning seems to be sloppily implemented.
